# Equations of the tangent planes to the sphere

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry, spheres

Find the equations of the tangent planes to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2-10x+2y+26z-113=0$ which are parallel to the straight lines $\frac{x+5}{2}=\frac{y-1}{-3}=\frac{z+13}{2}$ and $\frac{x+7}{3}=\frac{y+1}{-2}=\frac{z-8}{8}$.

Attempt:

Let the tangent plane be:

$ax+by+cz+d=0$ It is parallel to the given two straight line, so we have
$2a-3b+2c=0, ~~3a-2b+8c=0$ Cross-multipling

$$\frac{a}{4}=\frac{b}{2}=\frac{c}{-1}$$

My process shall not give me answer. Please help.

Comment: The planes given in the answer are not parallel to the second line. Perhaps the answers are not correct.

Comment: @Muralidharan Deleted the answer. Please suggest the further process of solution.

Comment: The tangent plane will be of the form $4x+2y-z-k=0$, the center of the sphere is $(5,-1,-13)$ and radius is $\sqrt{308}$. You can find $k$ using the fact that the plane is at a distance equal to the radius of the sphere from the center of the sphere.

Comment: With the equations given and continuing the calculus already done, the equations of the planes are : $$4x+2y-z=31\pm 14\sqrt{33}$$ Since they are different from those expected, probably there is a typo in the given equations.